# Another word for potion that isn't a liquid

Tags: word-choice

> A potion (from Latin potio "drink", in turn derived from Greek poton "that which one drinks") is a consumable magical medicine drug or poison.

What about a substance that is a consumable magical medicine drug or poison? For example, alcohol is a potion that increases a user's strength, but also decreases a user's attack (hence, it's a poison and medicine at the same time). But ammonia can increase a user's strength, if sniffed in its crystalline form. What's the correct term?

Comment: Just say no to drugs! Don

Comment: ammonia is not food. @GregLee

Comment: @DonLarynx, good point.

Comment: _magic mushroom_?

Comment: What about a dose?  (Pharmacology) med a specific quantity of a therapeutic drug or agent taken at any one time or at specified intervals.

Comment: What's wrong with 'substance'?

Comment: Sorry, @Don Larynx. I misunderstood the requirements. I couldn't think of another more correct so I've deleted. Best of luck. :-)

Comment: Lacking a ready-made word: Pharmacon was in The Imperial Dictionary of 1883 as a medicine, drug or poison, from Gk pharmakon. https://books.google.com/books?id=oHwCAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA426&dq=%22pharmakon%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GxvoVLTbEoXVggSssoLQBg&ved=0CBwQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=%22pharmakon%22&f=false *Potion* was a generic drink, that slowly evolved into its magical and poisonous meaning. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=potion *Melange* is a generic mixture that could be laced with malicious and magical meaning, and it even starts with a meaner sound.

Comment: Alcohol increases a user’s strength but decreases their attack? What does that even mean?!?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Sounds like D&D/RPG terminology to me: The drinker may be buzzed enough to think he can take on the world (more [strength](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Strength)) but also enough that his aim's a little off (less [attack](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Base_Attack_Bonus_%28Term%29)).

Comment: @dingo_dan That was my immediate thought, too, but that's not English. If it's just about RPG terminology, we should probably move this to Gamers.SE or something like that.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't think it has to be just about RPG terminology. The OP uses RPG terms to describe what motivated the question, much as one might use a quote from history. The question is asking for a term for non-liquid (crystalline, pill, etc.) stimulants/toxins, which fits here under hyper/hyponyms and SWR. I don't know enough about RPGs to say, but if they *don't* have a term for this, it seems like it would end up a candidate to move back to ELU (or maybe some SE about health).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure I've seen *[bolus](http://i.word.com/imedical/bolus) *used in this sort of sense although it just means a large pill. That would serve you for oral consumption. The inhalant sense doesn't rule out a potion, which could be "sniffed", and in your example the ammonia isn't really consumed.

Otherwise you've got *[physic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/physic)* as an old word for medicine which might be of some use.

While in pharmacology *[elixir](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/elixir) is specifically liquid, this is not the case in other (alchemical) uses.